# Export product with Category Names

Tags: collection, export, category-products

I'm trying to exports products programatically with their category names. Here is my code to export it.

```
 <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 

foreach($collection as $product) {

  $_cat = array();
  $categoryName = array();

  foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $Id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($Id);
  $categoryName = $_cat->getName();
  }
    fputcsv($output, array(
            $product->getSku(),
            $categoryName            
                     )
    );
}
?>
```

Products are associated to multiple categories. Though the code exports only one of the category names. How I can export all the category names associated to them programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out. `implode()` did the trick for me.

Here is the updated code:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //Select everything from the table
 ->addUrlRewrite(); //Generate nice URLs
foreach($collection as $product) {
  $_cat = array();
  $categoryName = array();

  foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $Id) {
  $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($Id);
   $categoryName[] = $_cat->getName();
  }
  $comma_separated = implode(",", $categoryName);
    fputcsv($output, array(
           $comma_separated,

            str_replace('export.php/','',Mage::getBaseUrl()).$product->getUrlPath($category)
                     )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: @ amitshree : our default data-flow profiles export return category id, how can i change to category name?

Comment: @Rathinam To achieve that you need to overwrite core and do the modifications there.

Comment: could u pls help me

Comment: @Rathinam: I believe that requires a lot of customization. Maybe you can export category name separately using above method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that $product->getCategoryIds() returns an array, and you are using it later $Id to load the category. Also you can try this instead to load the categories for the store you want:

```
$rootId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like'=> "1/$rootId/%"));

$categories->count();
```

Comment: Kindly check my completed code above and suggest where I need to make the modification. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that

```
$categoryName = $_cat->getName();
```

is not overriding the previous category name ?
Maybe try with array_push($categoryName, $_cat->getName).

Comment: Tried `foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $Id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($Id);
  $categoryName = array_push($categoryName, $_cat->getName);
  }
    fputcsv($output, array(
            $product->getSku(),
            $categoryName            
                     )
    ); ` and it's exporting category id(only 1) to the csv.  Please check the complete code above.